# How to write a number or string in LaTeX elevated left of the main text

Tags: latex

I have a question concerning LaTeX. I have the symbol 99mTc which I need to have: up-elevated(99m) and Tc at the main line of text. How can I do it?

Thank you

P.S. you can see here at the first line how I need it to be: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technetium-99m

Comment: As a side-note, there seems to be some inconsistencies on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technetium-99m) you reference. Some placed use 99Tc, others use 99mTc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a chemical typesetting package like [`mhchem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem). Additionally, if you're going to use this symbol often, define a macro to re-use when you need it - it promotes consistency:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\newcommand{\Technetium}{\ce{^{99m}Tc}}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Technetium-99m} is a metastable nuclear isomer of technetium-99, symbolized as 
\Technetium, that is used in tens of millions of medical diagnostic procedures annually, 
making it the most commonly used medical radioisotope.

\end{document}
```

Note that this no-argument macro should be used as `\Technetium{}` whenever it should be followed by a space, as TeX gobble spaces following a control sequence.

Comment: Thank you Werner! My only problem now is that I cannot put the symbol for Tc at the title of the section...

Comment: @AndréMiguelMonteiro: This stems from the fact that sectional commands are written to file for use in the ToC, and this writing is prone to premature expansion. You could prepend the macro with `\protect` inside the `\section` title, but it's easier to just make the macro robust. For that change `\newcommand` into `\DeclareRobustCommand` and you're done.

Comment: @Thank you Werner I managed to solve the problem by adding and modifying the following packages:

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\bookmarksetup{numbered,open}

and then write this: 

\subsection{Radiopharmaceutical Production of \texorpdfstring{\ce{^{99m}Tc}}{\text99msuperior Tc}}